# Accessing the link inside the <li> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a navbar with an unordered list with structure of `<a></a>` tag inside the `<li></li>.`
This is what it looks like:

```js
document.querySelector('.nav-links').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.target.classList.contains('nav-link')) {
    const id = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    console.log(id);
    document.querySelector(id).scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#section-1" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#section-2" class="nav-link">Products</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#section-3" class="nav-link">Benefits</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#section-4" class="nav-link">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#section-5" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can access the  tag directly even if i clicked the outside of the link like in the screenshot below:

[image]

but the problem is that i need the value on the `href` so i can still change the view of my website when the

tag is clicked and not only when the  tag is clicked.
is there any way i can achieve this?

Comment: There are no `id` attributes on anything to match the link `href`s. `document.querySelector(id)` will never match.

Comment: Hi @slashroot but the problem to that will be the same as my current problem right since even though i click the <li> tag it won't do anything unless i click the <a> tag. Currently i'm thinking of doing instead of <li><a></a></li> i'm gonna do <a><li></li></a>

Comment: @phuzi thats not the issue here, and `id` is an assigned variable and works correctly.

Comment: HI @phuzi, it works when i click the <a> tag directly, it is getting the href of the <a> tag. but the problem is when i click the <li> tag i can't get the href value of the <a> tag

Comment: @ElijahLeis Actually with CSS you could achieve what your talking about. Keep it <li><a></a></li> but using CSS, make your a tag display block and take up the whole width/height of the LI. That will make sure that whenever you click within the LI bounds its actually the A being clicked.

Comment: Yes, what @slashroot said. It makes little sense to have a clickable area outside of the links to begin with here. And once you make the link cover the whole LI, this should probably not even need any JS at all any more - you can simply set [`scroll-behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) for your page via CSS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the element clicked was the link, otherwise find it:

```js
document.querySelector('.nav-links').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
  e.preventDefault();
  const link = e.target.classList.contains('nav-link') ? e.target : e.target.querySelector('a');
  const id = link.getAttribute('href');
  console.log(id);
  document.querySelector(id)?.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});
```

```css
.box::before { content: attr(id); }

.box {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 50vh;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#section-1" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#section-2" class="nav-link">Products</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#section-3" class="nav-link">Benefits</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#section-4" class="nav-link">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#section-5" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="box" id="section-1"></div>
<div class="box" id="section-2"></div>
<div class="box" id="section-3"></div>
<div class="box" id="section-4"></div>
<div class="box" id="section-5"></div>
```

Comment: Man, i didn't thought that i can use it like that. Thanks a lot mate! I really learned new things again today and what you did is really clever!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the click event to `ul` you can bind that to `li`.

```js
function onLinkClicked(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.classList.contains('nav-link')) {
    const id = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    document.querySelector(id).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
}
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item'))
  .forEach((node) => node.addEventListener('click', onLinkClicked))
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#section-1" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#section-2" class="nav-link">Products</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#section-3" class="nav-link">Benefits</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#section-4" class="nav-link">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#section-5" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="box" id="section-1">Home Section</div>
<div class="box" id="section-2">Products Section</div>
<div class="box" id="section-3">Benefits Section</div>
<div class="box" id="section-4">About Section</div>
<div class="box" id="section-5">Contact Section</div>
```

Comment: A delegate listener on the `ul` is perfectly fine.